# Clock drift in a VirtualBox guest

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, clock

I've done this command this morning:

```
root@xxx:01:21:17:/home/xxx$ date --set "2015-08-06 02:54"
Thu Aug  6 02:54:00 WIB 2015
root@xxx:02:54:00:/home/xxx$ hwclock --set --date="2015-08-06 02:54"
```

later on that day, I check the clock it should be `08:00`, but it shows a delay by `10 minutes`:

```
root@xxx:07:49:59:/home/xxx$ date
Thu Aug  6 07:50:00 WIB 2015
root@xxx:07:50:00:/home/xxx$ hwclock
Thu Aug  6 07:50:01 2015  .392298 seconds
```

What are the possible cause of this? I'm using 64-bit ArchLinux under VirtualBox

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 4.0.4-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 22 03:05:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The timezone is GMT+7

```
$ date +'%:z %Z'
+07:00 WIB
$ strings /etc/localtime | tail -n 1
WIB-7
```

As suggested on the comment, installing `ntp` temporarily solves this problem:

```
sudo pacman -S ntp
sudo systemctl enable ntpd
sudo systemctl start ntpd
timedatectl set-ntp true
timedatectl
```

but after one day, the time drifting again:

```
      Local time: Fri 2015-08-07 23:52:10 WIB --> 30 minutes late
  Universal time: Fri 2015-08-07 16:52:10 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2015-08-07 16:52:10
       Time zone: Asia/Jakarta (WIB, +0700)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: possibly a failing cmos battery

Comment: Are the clocks on your host and guest both slow, or is it just the guest? If both, then it is a problem with the time on your host system (maybe what @gwillie mentioned), otherwise it is a Virtualbox problem.

Comment: I've had problems with vm's and clock skew but not for a while. I always run ntp to makes sure. Internet search for `virtualbox clock skew ` to get some config options that may help you

Comment: @NDZ only on the guest (ArchLinux)

Comment: I have this hyperlink in my favorites: http://hydra.geht.net/tino/howto/virtualbox/linux/time/

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with the ***paravirtualisation***

Changing the ***para-virtualisation*** parameter in virtual box will help solving the issue.
In the settings of your virtualbox machine go to:
**System > Acceleration**
[image]

Hopping that will help many people.

Comment: Interesting, makes sense but do you have any more information on this? Why does it happen and with which settings?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a virtual box question than Linux.
  Please check the virtual box documentation as they have some comments on why there could be some discrepancies (tldr: the clock is shared between the two computers).  As suggested above, use ntp. Sudo apt-get  install  ntp.  It doesn't require any configuration, only network access.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/setting-clock-source-vm.html#GUID-E55821AE-E001-4490-9545-DBAB652D896E), somehow hidden away in Oracle's database docs on that subject that fixed it for me. After setting my clock source from `tsc` to `acpi_pm` the problem completely disappeared. You can list the available clock sources in your guest linux system with:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
```

Then try different ones without restarting with:

```
 echo "acpi_pm" > /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

If you find a setting that does not introduce time drift, then you can set it as a boot parameter in your grub config by adding `clocksource=acpi_pm` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the `/etc/default/grub` file and then updating the grub config `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on the comment, installing `ntp` solves this problem:

```
sudo pacman -S ntp
sudo systemctl enable ntpd
sudo systemctl start ntpd
timedatectl set-ntp true
timedatectl
```